# call linkbutton event on page load in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am calling the link button event on page load which is not working as there is no sender for the click.
but when I tried to create a new object it gives an error.

```
 lnkFirst_Click(new object(),new CommandEventArgs());
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: do check this, hope it will helps you a bit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
lnkFirst_Click(sender,e)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Webforms.

By default your "linkbutton event" does not exist.
You need to create a method for it (usually with an Object/EventArgs as argument)

```
void lnkFirst_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

After that, you add a handler to call that function (You will probably want to add that on the page load), which is triggered when the request was called with a click on the linkbutton.

```
lnkFirst.Click += new EventHandler(this.lnkFirst_Click);
```

To call it manually, you can do:

```
lnkFirst_Click(lnkFirst, null);
//or
lnkFirst_Click(null, null);
```

That depends on if you NEED or not to use the `Object Sender` or the `EventArgs e`.

Of course you can also rename the `lnkFirst_Click` method to whathever name you want.